# How to populate data with id to dialog box in Android?

Tags: android, dialog, populate, listboxitems

I would like to get id from dialog box after user select text that populated in dialog box.
How can I populate data with hidden id to dialog box from web service?

Comment: Show related part of code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you gave, I'm guessing you want something like

```
EditText dialogBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourDialogBox);
int id = dialogBox.getId();
```

If you are referring to an actual Dialog object, I do not see any way to directly reference the ID of the dialog other than possibly

```
yourDialogObject.getOwnerActivity().getTaskId();
```

Without more info it is hard to say what exactly you are looking for.